# Sharepoint 2013: How to make Promoted links responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sharepoint-2013

I'm having (as expected) big times truble trying to implement twitter bootstrap in Sharepoint, anyway, most of the things works properly exept when i'm trying to make the promoted links reponsive.

I'm trying to achieve my task by assign to them the class name "col-md-4", I'm doing this by changing via jquery the class name in that way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ2').removeClass('ms-promlink-body');
            $('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ2').addClass('row container-fluid');
            $('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ2').children().removeClass('ms-tileview-tile-root');
            $('#promotedlinksbody_WPQ2').children().addClass('col-md-4');
        });
```

I'm removing the class named 'ms-promlink-body'and 'ms-promlink-body' because otherwise nothing is working (apparently maybe sharepoint is overriding it).

By the way this system is half working and half not, here is some screenshots:

**Full screen visualization**
[image: Fullscreen visualization]

**Medium devices visaulization**
[image]

**Small devices visualization**
[image]

Now the focal point of my question is: does anybody knows why also if i'm changing the class name from 'col-md-4' to 'col-md-5' or 'col-md-3' or any other col-md-values', nothing changes in my visualization? Why the behaviour is still the same??

Hope my question is clear enough, just in case ask. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint is overriding the behaviour of the col-md, just add !important on the class property and it's working.